# Angular isolated scope calling parent function

Tags: angularjs

I'm playing around with Angular and trying to learn more about scopes.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.color = 'green';
    $scope.sayHello = function(){
        console.log("HELLO FROM PARENT SCOPE");
    }
});

app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: 'true',
            scope: {
                color: '@colorAttr',
                sayHello: '&'
            },
      template: '<p style="background-color:{{color}}">Hello World',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.sayHello();
            }
  };
});
```

I'm trying to call the parent method sayHello() but when I use an isolated scope it wont allow me. I have read a little about using the & in the isolated scope but not sure I'm using it correctly.

```
HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" ng-app="myapp">
<head>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-model="color"/>
    <hello-world color-attr="{{color}}">Replaced</hello-world>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Show us your HTML too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to pass the method to the directive like this

```
<hello-world color-attr="{{color}}" say-hello="sayHello()">Replaced</hello-world>
```

**Explain**

When you create an isolated scope the parent scope is hidden from the directive, therefore hidding sayHello() in the link function. Nevertheless its still accessible through scope.$parent

The scope object passed in the directive initialization establishes mappings between the inner scope properties/methods and the directive's attributes,  which in turn can be linked to outer scope properties / methods.

In the above code sayHello inside the link function is mapped to the function with the same name in the parent scope as was mapped in the attribute say-hello.

Hope I was more clear this time :)

Comment: What I don't get is if I was to give the scope as the parent then I can call it directly inside the link method. Like I have done above. Can you explain the difference?

Comment: HOw can I pass a parameter to the parent function from inside the isolated scope

Answer (score 0):

> You can also call parent controller method from isolated by passing
>   function reference. the following code help to understand the how you
>   can use.

```
<hello-world color-attr="{{color}}" say-hello="sayHello">Replaced</hello-world>

app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: 'true',
            scope: {
                color: '@colorAttr',
                sayHello: '='
            },
      template: '<p style="background-color:{{color}}">Hello World',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.sayHello();
            }
  };
});
```